# Asp.Net Mvc 4 Entity.Command Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem about entity. First I share my code.

#### Tale.cs

```
public class Tale
{
    public int TaleId { get; set; }
    public string TaleName { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string VoicePath { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }  
}
```

#### My function

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Tale> GetAllTalesByCategorySeoName(string category)
{
    return TaleService.FindAllTale().Where(x => x.Category.CategorySeoName == category).ToList();
}
```

And this code gives an error like that "An exception of type 'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code". if I delete .ToList() It's gives a same error again.

Thanks for all replies.

### Answer

@mostruash said "check the InnerException" and I see this error "Command associated with this , there is already an open DataReader must be closed first."(I translated to English maybe it isn't exact mean!). I realize after the TaleService.FindAllTale() method return IEnumerable object and I try to add Where() method in GetAllTalesByCategorySeoName(string category). But when I try to this TaleService.FindAllTale() haven't closed. And I delete Where() method. Finally, I editted my FindAllTale() method in TaleService.

#### TaleService.cs

```
public IEnumerable<Tale> FindAllTale(string category)
    {
        return TaleRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.Category.CategorySeoName == category);
    }
```

Comment: What is a TaleService and what does FindAllTale() do? We cannot help you unless you answer those. Moreover, run in Debug mode and check the InnerException of the EntityCommandExecutionException that is being thrown.

Comment: TaleService have about like a CRUD function. FindAllTale is find all tale, just it. TaleService.FindAllTale return IEnumerable<Tale> and its working. I try and I take all tale. But I want to filter with categorySeoName.

Comment: As I said, check the InnerException and put it in your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I checked the InnerException and solved problem. I'm sorry for disturbing u. I couldn't think to check InnerException.

Comment: You could post the inner exception and your solution as an answer to the question in case anyone else would encounter this problem.